# Intellij Idea dont allow to run app on real device

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I have Idea 12 with configured Oracle SDK 1.6, and with Android SDK,

```
$ ./adb devices
List of devices attached 
S5830c10eb068   device
```

Also, Eclipse allows me to run project directly on physical device, but Idea is just able to see that device - `S5830c10eb068`(Samsung gt-s5830, android 2.3.6) in some windows:

[image]

but even when I choose 'USB device' in 'Run Configuration' - nothing happens:

[image]

What should I do?

Also, there is errors in logcat after device plugged in:

```
02-20 03:59:35.419: ERROR/RingtoneManager(158): getActualDefaultRingtoneUri : content://media/internal/audio/media/9
02-20 03:59:35.419: ERROR/RingtoneManager(158): Uri.parse(uriString) : content://media/internal/audio/media/9
02-20 03:59:35.439: ERROR/RingtoneManager(158): getActualDefaultRingtoneUri : content://media/internal/audio/media/9
02-20 03:59:35.439: ERROR/RingtoneManager(158): Uri.parse(uriString) : content://media/internal/audio/media/9
02-20 03:59:35.539: ERROR/MountService(158): ### notifyShareAvailabilityChange :: method = ums, avail = false
02-20 03:59:35.549: ERROR/MountService(158): notifyShareAvailabilityChange :: send ACTION_UMS_CONNECTED
02-20 03:59:38.609: ERROR/MountService(158): ### notifyShareAvailabilityChange :: method = ums, avail = true
02-20 03:59:38.619: ERROR/MountService(158): notifyShareAvailabilityChange :: send ACTION_UMS_CONNECTED
02-20 03:59:39.639: ERROR/RingtoneManager(158): getActualDefaultRingtoneUri : content://media/internal/audio/media/42
02-20 03:59:39.639: ERROR/RingtoneManager(158): Uri.parse(uriString) : content://media/internal/audio/media/42
02-20 03:59:39.919: ERROR/RingtoneManager(158): getActualDefaultRingtoneUri : content://media/internal/audio/media/42
02-20 03:59:39.919: ERROR/RingtoneManager(158): Uri.parse(uriString) : content://media/internal/audio/media/42
02-20 03:59:40.219: ERROR/RingtoneManager(158): getActualDefaultRingtoneUri : content://media/internal/audio/media/42
02-20 03:59:40.219: ERROR/RingtoneManager(158): Uri.parse(uriString) : content://media/internal/audio/media/42
02-20 04:00:12.689: ERROR/RingtoneManager(158): getActualDefaultRingtoneUri : content://media/internal/audio/media/9
02-20 04:00:12.689: ERROR/RingtoneManager(158): Uri.parse(uriString) : content://media/internal/audio/media/9
02-20 04:00:12.699: ERROR/RingtoneManager(158): getActualDefaultRingtoneUri : content://media/internal/audio/media/9
02-20 04:00:12.699: ERROR/RingtoneManager(158): Uri.parse(uriString) : content://media/internal/audio/media/9
02-20 04:00:12.809: ERROR/MountService(158): ### notifyShareAvailabilityChange :: method = ums, avail = false
02-20 04:00:12.819: ERROR/MountService(158): notifyShareAvailabilityChange :: send ACTION_UMS_CONNECTED
02-20 04:00:22.859: ERROR/MountService(158): ### notifyShareAvailabilityChange :: method = ums, avail = true
02-20 04:00:22.889: ERROR/MountService(158): notifyShareAvailabilityChange :: send ACTION_UMS_CONNECTED
02-20 04:03:52.719: ERROR/MountService(158): ### notifyShareAvailabilityChange :: method = ums, avail = false
02-20 04:03:52.729: ERROR/MountService(158): notifyShareAvailabilityChange :: send ACTION_UMS_CONNECTED
02-20 04:04:25.659: ERROR/MountService(158): ### notifyShareAvailabilityChange :: method = ums, avail = true
02-20 04:04:25.669: ERROR/MountService(158): notifyShareAvailabilityChange :: send ACTION_UMS_CONNECTED
02-20 04:59:09.369: ERROR/RingtoneManager(158): getActualDefaultRingtoneUri : content://media/internal/audio/media/9
02-20 04:59:09.369: ERROR/RingtoneManager(158): Uri.parse(uriString) : content://media/internal/audio/media/9
02-20 04:59:09.389: ERROR/RingtoneManager(158): getActualDefaultRingtoneUri : content://media/internal/audio/media/9
02-20 04:59:09.399: ERROR/RingtoneManager(158): Uri.parse(uriString) : content://media/internal/audio/media/9
```

Also, if I chose 'Show chooser dialog' and then select 'run' from 'Run' menu - there is the same window as on the second picture opens.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to edit **Defaults**, but you need to create a **new** run configuration instead.

Refer to [this documentation section for details](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html).

Once configuration is created, you will be able to select it in the drop-down on the toolbar and Run/Debug buttons will become available.

Answer (score 1):

`Run --> Edit Configurations... --> General --> Show Chooser Dialog --> OK`

Then run it again.

Answer (score 0):

Select "show choice dialog" and you show dialog with device ID

Comment: selected, and what I have to do after that? If I now select 'run' from 'Run' menu - there is the same window as on the second picture opens.

Comment: @may be I could give you access to my computer via teamviewer and you will see that?

Comment: yes, this choice is in Run dialog =>general tab. It the first radio button

Answer (score 0):

On idea 13,in run configuration -> General -> target device -> USB devices

Answer (score 0):

Maybe related to seeing the device in the chooser: On my machine the device is only in the list after I killed the ADB process manually (Task Manager -> "adb.exe *32"). Before that, there were no device in list or OK button grayed out.
(IntelliJ IDEA 13.0.2 Community)